The pn junction under reverse bias process
I have a question about the reverse bias p-n junction. While applying reverse voltage, the material is being exposed to a reverse field from the battery and we assume that this field is at the depletion width. Only at the beginning before any increasing in the depletion width this field is just added to the built in field. But as time goes on, the depletion width is getting wider and wider, which means that the depletion width increases. My question is what is happening to the external battery field? At the beginning of the process it was appearing as a separate physical entity and is superimposed on the original built-in field, but at the end of the process we consider the total field due to the new charges in this region. I will provide a photo from Neamen.

As you see, the applied field that is above the charges’ field appears as a physical entity at the beginning of the process then disappears and all that appears is the new charges’ field. What happened to this applied field that made it disappear?

Are you asking how the field in the depletion region changes in time when you apply a reverse bias, or are you only concerned with steady state?

@Matt, yes how the field changes with time , initially when the reverse field is applied it must get added to the initial built in field , and as time goes on the built in field gets bigger , what then happen to the the intial reverse field that appears in the picture i uploaded

When you say "it must get added to the initial built in field" what are you describing? What does that look like to you and how is it different than after some time?

@Matt, while applying the reverse bias intially the battery produce some electric filed lets name it $E_{app}$ this as a vector will be in the same direction as the $E_{built in}$ and they will be added together as a simple vector summation , while advancing in time the built in field $E_{built in}$ is increasing , the vector $E_{app}$ what is happening to it ?

The built in field does not change as a function of time or applied bias. The extra field is not "built in". I dont have my copy of Neamen on hand, but it has an equation for built in field. You will find that applied bias is not a part of it.

@Matt, Imagine a situation there are two vectors one of them represent the charges electric field and the other represent the applied field and the net is their sum , as time progress the depletion Width is getting increased due to the more charges that filing the region so in order to have the net field the same the applied field vector must decrease in length, I abstracted the discussion on the vector representation, like the picture provided in question the internal field is the charges field the external field above it , this applied field must at steady state disappear, how is this done ?

The portion of the electric field in the depletion region caused by external application of a bias does not go away until you remove that external bias. The applied field remains applied until it is un-applied.

@Matt, but what appear in the depletion region is just due to the charges , What Iam describing that there is an external field in this region rather than the charges, this one doesn't depend on the charges it's a constant applied field, As I said imagine a vector represent the applied field and another vector represent the charges field just getting added in free space , at steady state we just considering the charges field, what did happen to the external applied field the material is exposed to that field and we Just considering the one results from the fixed charges


what appear in the depletion region is just due to the charges , What Iam describing that there is an external field in this region rather than the charges, this one doesn't depend on the charges it's a constant applied field, As I said imagine a vector represent the applied field and another vector represent the charges field just getting added in free space , at steady state we just considering the charges field, what did happen to the external applied field the material is exposed to that field and we Just considering the one results from the fixed charges

There is no such distinction. The external field you are talking about is established by appling a voltage across the diode terminals. It takes a short amount of time for the depletion region to charge. The field does not increase instantly.
On the other hand if you truly mean dropping an unconnected diode in an electric field. Then charges at the outside edges will rearrange to cancel the field internal to the diode and the junction will look the same as if you had never added this extra field.

No I don't mean unconnected diode , the reverse bias make the pn junction exposed to an external field, it's job to widen the width, after widening the width , where does this external field goes? And why doesn't the process continue, why the widen of depletion Width stop at certain point what makes this process stop ?

I mean that I exposed the material to a certain field this certain field get the width wider , after getting it wider it must vanish, because it doesn't vanish the depletion Width will get wider and wider, my question how does it vanish?

@Abdelrahman_200 Why do you think the width must continue to increase?

It the material is still exposed to the external field then this field will still do it's job to widen the depletion Width

@Abdelrahman_200 Once the field in the depletion region equals the combination of the externally applied field and the built in field the width will no longer change. The field outside the depletion region would be 0 (per the usual approximation) and drift current would be 0. Even if the depletion region width wanted to change, there wouldn't be any charges coming in or leaving to allow it to do so.

So you say once the total Field inside the depletion Width become equal to the sum of the intial built in field + the external field, the process Will stop , by that you mean at the end of the process the external field is not Penetrarting the depletion Width any more ? Because the field inside the depletion Width is due to charges only , but you say when the Field due to charges only become equal to the external field plus the intial built in field, what has happened to the external field then ?

@Abdelrahman_200 I think you need to be more specific about exactly how you are generating these fields. Since your answer seems to lie in those details. Neamen is talking about applying a voltage at the diode terminals (and skipping for the moment exactly how those terminals work, but that detail isnt needed for this)
